# block requests using site's ip

Tags: security, iis, ip, urlscan

Is it possible to block all requests that use the IP address rather than the domain name for a site on IIS? For example, i'd like to block https://104.100.100.2 but not https://somesite.com (which resides at the dummy ip of 104.100.100.2). I've tried using URLScan 3, but was unable to build a working rule. Thanks!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx

I'm sure setting the host header achieves this? See the link I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx

Have a look here and bind to the publicly accessible domain name - should do the trick (IIS won't respond to requests that haven't accessed using the https://somesite.com)

Not sure how else to do it...

Dave